# Why Does this Procedure throw an error at Else when Compiling

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014-express

Fairly simple sql procedure to see if a field in table is equal to true when the records fall between two dates.  The aim is to count the instances of tue and if the count comes to more than one return true in the output parameter.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CheckIfLandingsForPeriodHaveBeenPosted @startDate DATE,
@endDate DATE,
@LandingsPosted BIT OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON


  IF (SELECT 
        COUNT (
        lh.Posted
      FROM LandingHeaders lh
      WHERE lh.LandingDate1 BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
      AND lh.Posted = 1)
    > 0
    SET @LandingsPosted = 1
  ELSE
    SET  @LandingsPosted = 0

END
GO
```

I have tried adding an extra parenthesis after lh.Posted = 1 and removing the SET statement immediately after the ELSE but neither helps.

Firstly I'd like to know why this fails at the else statement, but I'm also wondering is there is a more elegant / efficient way to create such a query in the first place; in terms of pseudo code something along the lines of:

Check the posted field in records between these two dates, if any are found to be true return true

Comment: You are missing a ")' to close count function

Comment: did you missed a ')' after lh.Posted? i think should be select count(lh.posted) from ....

Comment: Doh  Stupid of me I'd been putting the extra parenthesis at the end.

Comment: If all you care about is the difference between *no* rows and *any* rows, use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188336.aspx) rather than asking the system to *count* the number of rows and then compare that value with zero. There's a chance that the system will be stupid enough to actually go through all of the rows and count them rather than being able to finish as soon as it's seen one row that qualifies.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  Thank you, I thought that there was probably a more efficient way to go about this, admittedly there will only ever be about 15 to 20 records to count in the first place, but I know that sql can be really efficient when the queries have been properly crafted.

Comment: "More than one" or more than 0 ?

Answer (score 2):

A compact and more efficient solution avoiding both `IF ... ELSE` and `COUNT` altogether:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CheckIfLandingsForPeriodHaveBeenPosted
    @startDate DATE, @endDate DATE,
    @LandingsPosted BIT = 0 OUTPUT   --<- Set default to FALSE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @LandingsPosted = 1 --<- Change to TRUE if at least one match is found
    FROM LandingHeaders lh
    WHERE lh.LandingDate1 BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
      AND lh.Posted = 1
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close `COUNT` with `)` try in following:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CheckIfLandingsForPeriodHaveBeenPosted @startDate DATE,
@endDate DATE,
@LandingsPosted BIT OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON


  IF (SELECT 
        COUNT(lh.Posted)
      FROM LandingHeaders lh
      WHERE lh.LandingDate1 BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
      AND lh.Posted = 1)
    > 0
    SET @LandingsPosted = 1
  ELSE
    SET  @LandingsPosted = 0

END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple syntax problem, as you can see the only change I did was in the count, you are missing one ')' so you query can't compile.

The procedure throws an error doesn't always tell you where the problem is, you can always assume that the problem is where it say it is.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CheckIfLandingsForPeriodHaveBeenPosted @startDate DATE,
 @endDate DATE,
 @LandingsPosted BIT OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON


 IF (SELECT 
    COUNT (lh.Posted)
  FROM LandingHeaders lh
  WHERE lh.LandingDate1 BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
  AND lh.Posted = 1)
> 0
SET @LandingsPosted = 1
ELSE
SET  @LandingsPosted = 0

END
GO
```